# JsonConverter CanConvert does not receive type

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a custom `JsonConverter`, which doesn't seem to be called correctly. I have created the converter, added it to the `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` collection and marked the property on the entity I am serialising with `[JsonConverter(typeof(SearchGeoConverter))]`, but even with these in place the converters `CanConvert` method never sees the type I am trying to convert. I only ever see, `string`, `int` and `JObject`.

My converter looks like this:

```
public class SearchGeoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(DbGeography).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var point = (DbGeography) value;
        var rawJson = string.Format("{{ \"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [{0}, {1}] }}", point.Latitude, point.Longitude);
        writer.WriteRaw(rawJson);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: class modifier is public ?

Comment: Yes, both the entity and the converter are public.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`CanConvert` does not get called when you mark something with `[JsonConverter]`.  When you use the attribute, Json.Net assumes you have provided the correct converter, so it doesn't bother with the `CanConvert` check.  If you remove the attribute, then it will get called by virtue of you passing the converter instance to the settings.  What you are seeing is Json.Net testing your converter for all the other property types.

**EDIT**

I put together a quick [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kYblzk) to show what I mean (code is also reproduced below for completeness).

With no changes the program, `CanConvert()` gets called on the `FooConverter` for all types *except* `Foo`, yet it still converts `Foo` correctly.

If you comment out the `[JsonConverter]` attribute on the `Wrapper.Foo` property, you can see that `CanConvert()` will now get called for type `Foo` by virtue of the `FooConverter` being included in the `JsonSerializerSettings`.

If you instead comment out the line in `Main` where the `FooConverter` is added to the settings, then `CanConvert` is never called for any type, yet `Foo` is still converted correctly due to the `[JsonConverter]` attribute applied to the `Foo` property in the `Wrapper` class.

So the takeaway here is that there are two mechanisms for indicating whether a converter should be used, and you don't need both.  You can apply an attribute, and that will tell Json.Net that a particular converter should be used for a particular property (or class) and it does not need to ask the converter first.  Alternatively, you can add the converter to the settings, in which case Json.Net has to ask each converter whether it can handle each type.  The former is a bit more efficient, while the latter is useful in situations where you don't own the source code for the class you're trying to convert.  Hope this makes sense.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        // Comment out the following line and CanConvert() never gets called on 
        // FooConverter for any type yet the FooConverter is still working due
        // to the JsonConverter attribute applied to Wrapper.Foo
        settings.Converters.Add(new FooConverter());
        settings.Converters.Add(new BarConverter());
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        Wrapper w = new Wrapper
        {
            Foo = new Foo
            {
                A = "bada",
                B = "boom",
            },
            Bar = new Bar
            {
                C = "bada",
                D = "bing"
            }
        };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(w, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    class Wrapper
    {
        // Comment out this attribute and CanConvert will be called on FooConverter
        // for type Foo due to the fact that the FooConverter has been added to the
        // JsonSerializerSettings
        [JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
        public Foo Foo { get; set; }
        public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
    }

    class FooConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            bool result = typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
            Console.WriteLine("FooConverter CanConvert() called for type " +
                              objectType.Name + " (result = " + result + ")");
            return result;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var foo = (Foo) value;
            JObject jo = new JObject();
            jo.Add("AplusB", new JValue(foo.A + " " + foo.B));
            jo.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class BarConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            bool result = typeof(Bar).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
            Console.WriteLine("BarConverter CanConvert() called for type " + 
                              objectType.Name + " (result = " + result + ")");
            return result;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var bar = (Bar) value;
            JObject jo = new JObject();
            jo.Add("CplusD", new JValue(bar.C + " " + bar.D));
            jo.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```